Puppeteer "could not find Chrome" node js standalone executable application (SEA)
I'm working on a project that uses Node SEA (https://nodejs.org/api/single-executable-applications.html) to create an .exe with the intention of converting a Quickbooks report saved as a CSV to invoice PDFs. The program works on my local machine and I bundled it to an .exe (which also works on my local machine) and sent it to the client, where the following error message occurs:

Error Text:

Error: Could not find Chrome (ver. 123.0.6312.58). This can occur if either 1. you did not perform installation before running the script (e.g. 'npx puppeteer browsers install chrome') or 2. your cache path is incorrectly configured (which is: C:\Users\username \ .cache\puppeteer). For (2) check out our guide on configuring puppeteer at https://pptr.dev/guides/configuration

Simplified puppeteer code:
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

const generatePDFBuffer = async function (html) {
  // Launch a new chrome instance
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    headless: true
  });

  // Create a new page
  const page = await browser.newPage();

  await page.emulateMediaType('print');

  // Set your html as the pages content
  await page.setContent(html, {
    waitUntil: 'domcontentloaded',
  });

  // Create a pdf buffer
  const pdfBuffer = await page.pdf({
    format: 'A4',
    printBackground: true, // required for basic styling, background colors
    preferCSSPageSize: true, // required for maintaining page margins when iterating over a table > 1 page
  });

  // Close the browser
  await browser.close();

  return pdfBuffer;
};

I tried adding a .cjs file to the root of my project per the puppeteer configuration dev guide, which seemed like that would be the root cause, but it didn't work: https://pptr.dev/guides/configuration.
Any help in troubleshooting this would be appreciated. You can clone this public repo to recreate the .exe and bug: https://github.com/alexcartaz/CSV-to-PDF.

Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?. Please provide a [mcve] of the code, packages, bundling commands, and error as text.

@ggorlen ok added error text and uploaded code snippet

OK, thanks. Code and errors look good. How are you building this? I'm not sure how to create your exe that fails. Still missing from my top comment: packages and bundling commands.

@ggorlen my attempted fix didn't work. I updated the post to include it and a way you can create the .exe to test yourself

Sorry, I don't see a command to create an exe in your post.
